# What do "space" and "shift" mean here?

Tags: metric-spaces, definition, dynamical-systems, isometry, equicontinuity

In his book [Poincaré's Legacies](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2009/01/whatsnew.pdf), Terence Tao gives the following definition of a dynamical system (p. xii):

> [...] a discrete or continuous dynamical system [...]  is simply a space $X$, together with a shift $T : X \to X$ (or family of shifts) acting on that space [...]

What do *space* and *shift* mean here? How is it different from a set $X$ and a function $X\to X$?

**Added**:

I suppose there must be a difference between space/shift and set/function since on page 215 Tao writes:

> Any finite dynamical system is both isometric and equicontinuous (as one can see by using the discrete metric).

Yet if we take $X=\{a,b,c\}$ and $f$ defined by $f(a)=b, f(b)=a, f(c)=b$, then there is no metric on $X$ that would make $f$ an isometry. Since for any metric $d$ holds $$0<d(a,c) \neq d(f(a),f(c))=d(b,b)=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [respective Scholarpedia entry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Dynamical_systems#Definition), there is really almost no difference between your understanding of dynamical system (a set with a mapping rule) and the definition from the book. The only subtlety is that space is a set with some additional structure (e.g., metric space, topological space or measurable space). If you are considering some space and (family of) mapping(s) (*shifts* in Tao's terminology) respects this structure (e.g., it is isometric/continuous/measurable), this sometimes gives you much more insight in dynamics of system.

Comment: Please take a look at one more quote from the book I added.

Comment: @Leo Note that on page 163 Tao defines finite systems as sets for which shift is a permutation of this finite set. This is what is violated in your example.

Comment: Thanks! And what if $X$ is infinite? Must $f$ then be a homeomorphism? I’m particularly interested in the context of the following statement on p. 215: “a topological dynamical system is isometric
if and only if it is equicontinuous”.

Comment: Yes, in Tao's notes it is said on page 165 :) "_Topological dynamical systems_ $( X, T ) = ( X,  \mathcal{F}, T )$, in which $X = ( X, \mathcal{F} )$ is a compact metrisable (and thus Hausdorff)topological space, and $T$ is a topological isomorphism (i.e. a homeomorphism)"